# Why should I care about using Tor Browser if I'm just an Joe Average?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Consider that:

1. I don't have reasons to be a target of Advanced Persistent Threats or State Funded Cracking, since I'm a Joe Average just browsing the average websites on the average web;
2. all my connections to the websites are HTTPS encrypted using modern ciphers;
3. most of my web browsing is done on my employer's network, and there are thousands of users there sharing the same IP address.

Should I have a reason to worry if I don't use Tor Browser all the time there? Who could be a threat to me? Which information is exposed about me?

Comment: Do you read about fingerprints, WebRTC and so on?

Comment: @phantomcraft I started using TOR before the Snowden leaks because I was paranoid about government, then I kept using because I was paranoid but my paranoia was confirmed, then I kept using because I was paranoid about employers, then I noticed I don't have a good reason to be afraid of government knowing who I am, since I already work inside the government and nothing is happening to harm me. So, no, I'm not aware of anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be an enemy of the state, to have privacy. Loading up a page with HTTPS versus loading up an HTTPS *via Tor* differ by an order of magnitude.

With HTTPS (only):

1. Your ISP can track the sites you visit.
2. The owners of the site you visit can track your IP down.

Surfing the net with Tor does hide your activity from both your ISP and those owners. It also comes with some pre-installed plugins such as NoScript that secure you from fingerprinting. It's designed to enhance your security, privacy, and to preserve you censorship resistance on the web.

Comment: "Your ISP can track the sites you visit." & "The owners of the site you visit can track your IP down." : most of my web surfing is made from workplace. There are thousands of people in there using the same IP(s) at the same time. I don't feel personally identified by the IP address.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah, it's not a matter of instant identification. It's a matter of population. Your workplace has much less users than the Tor network.

Comment: Your new argument is not clear enough for me. Could you please update your answer explaining why I should care about the IP address even when I share it with thousands of other users?

Comment: What I meant is simple: One anonymity strength's parameter is population. It's easier to track a person if you know it's 1 out of the 10 total workers, opposed to tracking a person if you only know he's using a network that's used by millions of people every day. Therefore, it's easier for the ISP and the site owners to track you down if they know you're using your workplace's IP.

Comment: Why would my workplace ISP take time and energy to try to figure out which person is accessing which website, from inside a big workplace network of thousands of users? I don't see the benefit the ISP get from all this work, if I'm not doing something illegal that the ISP must stop.

Comment: Because it can. If you don't care about this scenario, don't use Tor. But, Tor does grant you the option to hide from your ISP, for whatever reason. They are not going to analyze this themselves anyway; that's why there are analyzing companies.

Comment: I can steal a random person on the street, but I'm not doing it just because I can. Committing crimes has a cost on my freedom that I don't consider worth paying. Obviously deep packet inspection has a great cost in machinery, expertise and energy, and ISPs will not do it if they don't gain something that pays off all the trouble. Your thesis seems completely hypotetical. Or could you point to a real case on the news where ISPs cared about tracking people who are not their clients, but mere users of a network of a corporate client?

Comment: Just because it doesn't benefit you, specifically, to rob me, it doesn't mean I wouldn't want such protection. I'd obviously want to be sure nobody can rob me. I won't point to a real case, you can use the search engine for that. The problem remains; an entity knows your activity. If you don't care much, ok. No problem, don't use Tor. I only explain you that you get less anonymity that way.

Comment: You can't say "an entity knows my activity", but just "an entity COULD know my activity, if it had any value to them". I doubt an entity would benefit from knowing what Wikipedia articles I'm reading.

Comment: So, they may do, if they want. I don't care either about wikipedia articles, but for more important and undisclosed stuff, I want a more private approach.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to conceal something if you're doing nothing wrong - but your personal life is **just** your private matter, that's it! Using darknet is not something bad: it's quite a lot of kiddy porn, warez, drugs and guns in a clearnet as well - even more: there's more of such stuff! It's like the statement "crypto is bad" - oh, really? Let us make a badness rating of both crypto and fiat and measure the numeral criteria by the amount of guns, crime, bribe et cetera paid in a particular matter of exchange... Top-10 will have no even the whole crypto accumulated! The question is **who** is in control of people's actions and who can - or can't - rob others

Comment: I could not understand even a little of your argument. I'm not seeking illegal things on Onion (hidden) services, just accessing the default web through Tor relays.

Comment: Joe Averages don't use Onion Hidden Services and are not seeking illegal things on the internet, they just want to browse Average websites with Average content.

Comment: the thing is that IF someone wants to frame you - especially the government guys by whatever reason and/or occasion - the more they will succeed if they are able to trace, track and deanonimize you

Comment: That is a good point. Would you like to submit a new answer focused entirely on it? Potentially could be THE answer.

Comment: @BsAxUbx5KoQDEpCAqSffwGy554PSah Well, tell me what exact things you do want to be opened there - and I will add them covered to my answer. The topic itself is too wide for an answer size limit :)

Answer (score 0):

People don't use Tor because they want encryption (At least encryption not the main reason) people use Tor because they want "complete privacy" where no one knows who they are (And I doubt that the tor browser on the Windows system is anonymous enough)
There are several types of people:

1. Those who use tor browser because they think it will protect them from "hackers" (0 percent basic understanding about tor)
2. The people who use the Tor browser as a proxy/"VPN"
3. Those who use the Tor browser to access dark sites (Most people who enter the dark web do not understand what they are doing)
4. People who are reporters / those who are under totalitarian regime or dictatorial government (Usually such people will not use the tor browser they will use Tails which is an operating system built on the Tor network and uses only RAM memory and is usually installed on a USB Tails is one of the best operating systems for privacy)
5. People who just want privacy are not criminals, they are not reporters, they are not exactly in a dictatorial government, those people just want privacy, it is a basic right that everyone deserves

I think to some extent everyone needs privacy You need privacy too
You will be shocked by how much Google and advertising companies know about you
Watch this video to understand better:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4E4yAktjug

Comment: Hello. I'm the Case 2 combined with Case 5: I'm just accessing the default web through Tor relays, because I want privacy. But I'm not seeing the benefit of it, now that I'm sure that I'm not on the target of any 3 letter agency. Who am I hiding from? What am I hiding? I don't understand anymore, since the point in time when my paranoia was forced out with the right medication.